Finding maximum of multiple arrays in respect to their index, that can vary
Problem description:
I have got values that do correspond to specific conrer_ids, elements. From multiple sets of these values I need to find maximum ones and generate arrays containing conrer_ids, elements and their respective values.

example:
old values:




value




(0, 'element 0')
0.831994


(1, 'element 0')
0.575897


(2, 'element 0')
0.0241688


(3, 'element 0')
0.930143


(4, 'element 1')
0.43566


(5, 'element 1')
0.00264849


(6, 'element 1')
0.133718


(7, 'element 1')
0.171456



new values:




value




(4, 'element 1')
0.584522


(5, 'element 1')
0.784499


(6, 'element 1')
0.206276


(7, 'element 1')
0.96535


(8, 'element 2')
0.203246


(9, 'element 2')
0.429909


(10, 'element 2')
0.979901


(11, 'element 2')
0.950208



expected result:




0




(0, 'element 0')
0.831994


(1, 'element 0')
0.575897


(2, 'element 0')
0.0241688


(3, 'element 0')
0.930143


(4, 'element 1')
0.584522


(5, 'element 1')
0.784499


(6, 'element 1')
0.206276


(7, 'element 1')
0.96535


(8, 'element 2')
0.203246


(9, 'element 2')
0.429909


(10, 'element 2')
0.979901


(11, 'element 2')
0.950208



I am tried using pd.concat(), df.max(), but it seems to be too slow. So I was wondering, if there is faster alternative. I need to make this work on arrays of ~ 1e6 length. I also tried some groupby solution, but it was not too much faster.
Code That I used
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

ELEMENT_COUNT_TOTAL = 3
ELEMENT_OVERLAP = 1
ELEMENT_OFFSET = 1

if ELEMENT_COUNT_TOTAL < ELEMENT_OVERLAP + ELEMENT_OFFSET:
    raise ValueError("ELEMENT_COUNT_TOTAL should be greater than ELEMENT_OVERLAP + ELEMENT_OFFSET")

CORNER_COUNT_TOTAL = ELEMENT_COUNT_TOTAL * 4

_corner_ids = [i for i in range(CORNER_COUNT_TOTAL)]
_elements = [f"element {i // 4}" for i in range(CORNER_COUNT_TOTAL)]

old_elements = _elements[:(ELEMENT_OVERLAP + ELEMENT_OFFSET) * 4]
old_corner_ids = np.array(_corner_ids[:(ELEMENT_OVERLAP + ELEMENT_OFFSET) * 4])

new_elements = _elements[ELEMENT_OFFSET * 4 :ELEMENT_COUNT_TOTAL * 4]
new_corner_ids = np.array(_corner_ids[ELEMENT_OFFSET * 4 :ELEMENT_COUNT_TOTAL * 4])

def generate_values(count) -> np.ndarray:
    return np.random.rand(count)

old_values = generate_values(len(old_corner_ids))
new_values = generate_values(len(new_corner_ids))

old_df = pd.DataFrame({"value": old_values}, index=[old_corner_ids, old_elements])
new_df = pd.DataFrame({"value": new_values}, index=[new_corner_ids, new_elements])

print(old_df.to_markdown())
print()
print(new_df.to_markdown())
print()

combined_df = pd.concat([old_df, new_df], axis=1, keys=["old", "new"])
result_df = combined_df.max(axis=1)
print(result_df.to_markdown())

EDIT:
Here are results, what I have tried for 1e3 elements:
%%timeit -n 1000
result_df = pd.concat([old_df, new_df], axis=1).max(axis=1)

2.4 ms ± 34.2 μs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
%%timeit -n 1000
result_df = pd.concat([old_df, new_df]).groupby(level=[0, 1]).max()

2.82 ms ± 518 μs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%%timeit -n 1000
combined_df = (pd.concat([old_df, new_df], axis=0).reset_index().rename(columns={"level_0": "corner_id", "level_1": "element"}))
result_df = combined_df.groupby(["element", "corner_id"])["value"].max().reset_index()

2.02 ms ± 34 μs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
Thank you for any suggestions, have a wonderful day!

why pd.concat on vertical axis? isn't axis=0 is what you are looking for?
like this: combined_df = pd.concat([old_df, new_df], axis=0).reset_index().rename(columns={"level_1": "element"}).drop(columns=["level_0"])

Well, there was no specific reason. I was maybe not descriptive enough, but data can be unsorted, meaning that I can not drop corner_ids, because they do not necessary need to correspond to indexing by natural numbers. So for pd.concat I could use following:
result_df = (pd.concat([old_df, new_df], axis=0).reset_index().rename(columns={"level_0": "corner_id", "level_1": "element"}))
but I still need to preserve reference between values, elements, corner_ids.

Use groupby on the index and aggregate with max:
df = pd.concat([old_df, new_df]).groupby(level=[0, 1]).max()

Or combine with np.maximum:
df = old_df.combine(new_df, np.maximum, fill_value=-float("inf"))

Both will output:
                 value
0  element 0  0.831994
1  element 0  0.575897
2  element 0  0.024169
3  element 0  0.930143
4  element 1  0.584522
5  element 1  0.784499
6  element 1  0.206276
7  element 1  0.965350
8  element 2  0.203246
9  element 2  0.429909
10 element 2  0.979901
11 element 2  0.950208


I have tried .groupby() method previously, but I was rather wondering if there is some faster option.

Previously I was using np.maximum for comparison purposes, but I was not dealing with different entities, but it significantly faster.
From what I understand most of time is taken by pd.concat(), but not actual maximum search. So my reasoning was to do this without that optimally ?

You can use combine and np.maximum, I've updated the answer with that. A last option would be to try join and groupby.

In the end I decided to use np.where() instead
simplified code:
mask = array1[:, 1] < array2[:, 1]
array = np.where(mask, array1, array2)

